# Handling updates in OLAP system for e-commerce system using immutable stores

Tags: olap, star-schema

I have a digital commerce system that we have built in-house and it has been working fine. We now want to implement OLAP to provide our customers with advanced reporting and BI features.

While looking for the needed components I came across several "immutable" data stores which seem popular choices as data warehouses. Ex : Apache Druid, Clickhouse etc. These seem to work pretty well with a visualization tool like Metabase (or other similar ones).

What I am unable to figure is handling updates to records in such immutable stores. Like in any order management system, orders in our system also get updated (status, line items, quantities etc) over the course of their lifetime. In such a case how would one use these immutable stores?

Even if I were to use something like a star schema, I can see needing updates to both fact and dimension tables. Ex if a sale is recorded as a fact with its total revenue, the amount might need an update or the order might get cancelled, items can change etc.

The only way i can think of is to only push a transaction to the data warehouse after it is CLOSED aka frozen. In this case all metrics and reporting for in-process orders will have to be based on the main DB (aka OLTP DB).

Is that the only way out? Is there a better approach?

Comment: To only be able to report on `CLOSED` orders would be a pretty poor user experience for reporting, in most cases. There's nothing wrong with changing the data that's used in an OLAP warehouse. But if your question is *how* to do that technologically, then it would depend specifically on what your current database system is and which one you choose to use for your data warehouse.

Comment: @J.D. I agree. Analytics on open orders is essential. My current DB is MongoDB and I am considering Apache Druid (primarily because Metabase supports it) as the data warehouse.

Comment: Ah, too bad you're not using a RDBMS, some of them have built in features to support OLAP in the same database as OLTP so you don't have to implement a connector and manage the data in two places. Best of luck!

Comment: @J.D. Metabase supports MongoDB out of the box. I have it running that way on staging. But using the main DB for OLAP doesn't seem right to me. For the kind of explorative queries that our customers will possibly run, a column oriented storage (like in data warehouses) is better suited. Otherwise we will have to create a huge number of indexes on the main DB. Further OLAP queries shouldn't load the DB to the point that OLTP operations are affected. Hence the reason for a separate OLAP data warehouse. Nothing to do with RDBMS v/s NoSQL.

Comment: "*OLAP queries shouldn't load the DB to the point that OLTP operations are affected. Hence the reason for a separate OLAP data warehouse. Nothing to do with RDBMS v/s NoSQL.*" - Except that's not true when it's possible to re-use the same database for both OLTP and OLAP without having to add a "*huge number of indexes*", which is possible with the features of some RDBMS. For example, Microsoft SQL Server offers columnstore indexes - literally a single index can stage your OLTP rowstore data in a columnar-like format to make OLAP possible within the same database without having to manage 2 DBs.

Comment: "*a column oriented storage (like in data warehouses)*" - Data Warehouses aren't natively in columnar format. In fact, when speaking about the Star-schema that data warehouses typically follow, they are generally thought of in rowstore format. But either is applicable to a data warehouse.

Comment: @J.D. Point taken. Thank you for your inputs.

Comment: Np! Sorry, if I knew more about the standard infrastructure implementation between MongoDB and external OLAP database technologies, I'd post an answer. Best of luck!